# Do we need to initialize a component each time it is created in materialize?

Tags: javascript, meteor, material-design, angular-material, materialize

I have initialized select box and datepicker on template render but when I dyanmically create a new date element or select element using html in js , I am forced to write same initializing code for the element? Do we have a code when initialization is not needed each time a component is created?

e.g we have a template.

```
<template name="test">
 <select class="input-field" id="today_select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="today_date">
 <div id="runtime_date"></div>
</template>

<script>
 $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        close: 'Ok',
        closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
    });

 $('select').material_select();
</script>
```

now on selection of value 1 I have to add a new date element in div id runtime_date. but as I create the element I again need to rewrite this block of script just below the element addition otherwise datepicker wont show up.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    today: 'Today',
    clear: 'Clear',
    close: 'Ok',
    closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
});
```

so for each element I am creating dynamically I have to rewrite this initialization code. is it possible that I write this initialization only once and the newly created element also accepts this initialization?

Comment: It would be nice to see some code to illustrate your question.

Comment: Sir, I have put some code. hope you could help

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is wrong. You need to initialize the datepicker from the template's `onRendered` callback, like this.

THE HTML

```
<template name='datePickerTemplate'>
 <select class="input-field" id="today_select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>

 <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="today_date">
 <div id="runtime_date"></div>
</template>

<template name='outer'>
  {{ >datePickerTemplate }}
  {{ >datePickerTemplate }}
  {{ >datePickerTemplate }}
  {{ >datePickerTemplate }}
  <--! As many as you want -->
</template>
```

Also, if you're going to be rendering multiple instances of this datepicker, you should change `id` attributes to `class`.

THE JS

```
//This will fire every time an instance of datePickerTemplate is rendered.
Template.datePickerTemplate.onRendered( () => {
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
    today: 'Today',
    clear: 'Clear',
    close: 'Ok',
    closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
  });
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

Comment: I have done the same as you said. still for new elements it isn't working

Comment: @AkashKumar `onRendered` should fire each time a new component is created. Is the callback firing or not?

Comment: no. its not firing by self. we need to write the whole initialisation again.